# How to change Rotating point position to bottom in FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

How to change "Rotating point" position to the bottom (see image below) ?
[image: Expected Rotating Point]

And here is the link guide to configuration controls point of selecting object.
http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4#customization

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the angle to rotate the circle 180 degrees and the "Rotating point" will be at the bottom, if the object is something other than a circle add flipY to the mix to keep the object upright.

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="170" height="170"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.4/fabric.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var obj = new fabric.Triangle({
    fill: 'lime',
    top: 110,
    left: 110,
    angle: 180,
    flipY: true,
    borderColor: 'red',
    cornerColor: 'cyan',
    cornerSize: 9,
    transparentCorners: false
  });
  
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  canvas.add(obj);
  canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(0));
</script>
```

Comment: No @HelderSepu, It isn't my meaning, how will that image is a photo ( not circle shape ) ? I wan't move rotation point to the bottom, because, top of selected object we will put an extra context menu. I don't want rotating point is overlapped by that context menu. Do you have other recommendation for this case ?

Comment: @ThoBuiNgoc I was doing some test and you could add flipY in combination with the angle

Comment: Great solution, Thank you @Helder Sepulveda!

Comment: By doing `angle: 180`, everytime that I ll draw something, the shapes don't follow my mouse, but instead it goes to opposite direction which my mouse is moving.

Comment: @RodrigoChaves sorry but that sounds like a different problem, you should open a new question

Comment: how can I do it on textBox as textbox will be flipped?