# FabricJS - change the anchor side of the rotating point

Tags: rotation, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I'm trying to render a box with the rotating point in the bottom. Normaly, we can render a box with the property `hasRotatingPoint: true` and a handle appear in the top side of the box to the user rotate it.

What I want is to draw it in the bottom side of the box.

This could be achieved by set `angle: 180` and the rotating point will appear in the bottom side (as we rotate the box 180°) but I got a draw problem with this approach: the drawing process also rotated 180° and now my box goes in the opposite direction when I'm drawing.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit 1**

There is a very similar question about this problem here [How to change Rotating point position to bottom in FabricJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427490/how-to-change-rotating-point-position-to-bottom-in-fabricjs) but the solution accepted creates another bug in my context as described in the third paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

You need to rewrite 3 functions. `fabric.Object.prototype.calcCoords`, `fabric.Object.prototype.drawControls`, `fabric.Object.prototype.drawBorders`
Those 3 are almost the same, the only difference is that the mtr point is calculated different.

```js
fabric.Object.prototype.calcCoords= function(absolute) {
      var rotateMatrix = this._calcRotateMatrix(),
          translateMatrix = this._calcTranslateMatrix(),
          startMatrix = fabric.util.multiplyTransformMatrices(translateMatrix, rotateMatrix),
          vpt = this.getViewportTransform(),
          finalMatrix = absolute ? startMatrix : fabric.util.multiplyTransformMatrices(vpt, startMatrix),
          dim = this._getTransformedDimensions(),
          w = dim.x / 2, h = dim.y / 2,
          tl = fabric.util.transformPoint({ x: -w, y: -h }, finalMatrix),
          tr = fabric.util.transformPoint({ x: w, y: -h }, finalMatrix),
          bl = fabric.util.transformPoint({ x: -w, y: h }, finalMatrix),
          br = fabric.util.transformPoint({ x: w, y: h }, finalMatrix);
      if (!absolute) {
        var padding = this.padding, angle = fabric.util.degreesToRadians(this.angle),
            cos = fabric.util.cos(angle), sin = fabric.util.sin(angle),
            cosP = cos * padding, sinP = sin * padding, cosPSinP = cosP + sinP,
            cosPMinusSinP = cosP - sinP;
        if (padding) {
          tl.x -= cosPMinusSinP;
          tl.y -= cosPSinP;
          tr.x += cosPSinP;
          tr.y -= cosPMinusSinP;
          bl.x -= cosPSinP;
          bl.y += cosPMinusSinP;
          br.x += cosPMinusSinP;
          br.y += cosPSinP;
        }
        var ml  = new fabric.Point((tl.x + bl.x) / 2, (tl.y + bl.y) / 2),
            mt  = new fabric.Point((tr.x + tl.x) / 2, (tr.y + tl.y) / 2),
            mr  = new fabric.Point((br.x + tr.x) / 2, (br.y + tr.y) / 2),
            mb  = new fabric.Point((br.x + bl.x) / 2, (br.y + bl.y) / 2),
            mtr = new fabric.Point(mb.x - sin * this.rotatingPointOffset, mb.y + cos * this.rotatingPointOffset);
      }

      // if (!absolute) {
      //   var canvas = this.canvas;
      //   setTimeout(function() {
      //     canvas.contextTop.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 700);
      //     canvas.contextTop.fillStyle = 'green';
      //     canvas.contextTop.fillRect(mb.x, mb.y, 3, 3);
      //     canvas.contextTop.fillRect(bl.x, bl.y, 3, 3);
      //     canvas.contextTop.fillRect(br.x, br.y, 3, 3);
      //     canvas.contextTop.fillRect(tl.x, tl.y, 3, 3);
      //     canvas.contextTop.fillRect(tr.x, tr.y, 3, 3);
      //     canvas.contextTop.fillRect(ml.x, ml.y, 3, 3);
      //     canvas.contextTop.fillRect(mr.x, mr.y, 3, 3);
      //     canvas.contextTop.fillRect(mt.x, mt.y, 3, 3);
      //     canvas.contextTop.fillRect(mtr.x, mtr.y, 3, 3);
      //   }, 50);
      // }

      var coords = {
        // corners
        tl: tl, tr: tr, br: br, bl: bl,
      };
      if (!absolute) {
        // middle
        coords.ml = ml;
        coords.mt = mt;
        coords.mr = mr;
        coords.mb = mb;
        // rotating point
        coords.mtr = mtr;
      }
      return coords;
    }
    fabric.Object.prototype.drawControls=function(ctx, styleOverride) {
      styleOverride = styleOverride || {};
      var wh = this._calculateCurrentDimensions(),
          width = wh.x,
          height = wh.y,
          scaleOffset = styleOverride.cornerSize || this.cornerSize,
          left = -(width + scaleOffset) / 2,
          top = -(height + scaleOffset) / 2,
          transparentCorners = typeof styleOverride.transparentCorners !== 'undefined' ?
            styleOverride.transparentCorners : this.transparentCorners,
          hasRotatingPoint = typeof styleOverride.hasRotatingPoint !== 'undefined' ?
            styleOverride.hasRotatingPoint : this.hasRotatingPoint,
          methodName = transparentCorners ? 'stroke' : 'fill';

      ctx.save();
      ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle = styleOverride.cornerColor || this.cornerColor;
      if (!this.transparentCorners) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = styleOverride.cornerStrokeColor || this.cornerStrokeColor;
      }
      this._setLineDash(ctx, styleOverride.cornerDashArray || this.cornerDashArray, null);

      // top-left
      this._drawControl('tl', ctx, methodName,
        left,
        top, styleOverride);

      // top-right
      this._drawControl('tr', ctx, methodName,
        left + width,
        top, styleOverride);

      // bottom-left
      this._drawControl('bl', ctx, methodName,
        left,
        top + height, styleOverride);

      // bottom-right
      this._drawControl('br', ctx, methodName,
        left + width,
        top + height, styleOverride);

      if (!this.get('lockUniScaling')) {

        // middle-top
        this._drawControl('mt', ctx, methodName,
          left + width / 2,
          top, styleOverride);

        // middle-bottom
        this._drawControl('mb', ctx, methodName,
          left + width / 2,
          top + height, styleOverride);

        // middle-right
        this._drawControl('mr', ctx, methodName,
          left + width,
          top + height / 2, styleOverride);

        // middle-left
        this._drawControl('ml', ctx, methodName,
          left,
          top + height / 2, styleOverride);
      }

      // middle-top-rotate
      if (hasRotatingPoint) {
        this._drawControl('mtr', ctx, methodName,
          left + width / 2,
          top + height + this.rotatingPointOffset, styleOverride);
      }

      ctx.restore();

      return this;
    }
    fabric.Object.prototype.drawBorders=function(ctx, styleOverride) {
      styleOverride = styleOverride || {};
      var wh = this._calculateCurrentDimensions(),
          strokeWidth = 1 / this.borderScaleFactor,
          width = wh.x + strokeWidth,
          height = wh.y + strokeWidth,
          drawRotatingPoint = typeof styleOverride.hasRotatingPoint !== 'undefined' ?
            styleOverride.hasRotatingPoint : this.hasRotatingPoint,
          hasControls = typeof styleOverride.hasControls !== 'undefined' ?
            styleOverride.hasControls : this.hasControls,
          rotatingPointOffset = typeof styleOverride.rotatingPointOffset !== 'undefined' ?
            styleOverride.rotatingPointOffset : this.rotatingPointOffset;

      ctx.save();
      ctx.strokeStyle = styleOverride.borderColor || this.borderColor;
      this._setLineDash(ctx, styleOverride.borderDashArray || this.borderDashArray, null);

      ctx.strokeRect(
        -width / 2,
        -height / 2,
        width,
        height
      );

      if (drawRotatingPoint && this.isControlVisible('mtr') && hasControls) {

        var rotateHeight = height / 2;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, rotateHeight);
        ctx.lineTo(0, rotateHeight + rotatingPointOffset);
        ctx.stroke();
      }

      ctx.restore();
      return this;
    }
```

```css
body {
    background-color: ivory;
    padding:20px;
}
#canvas {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="666" height="444"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.js"></script>

<script>
  var obj = new fabric.Triangle({
    fill: 'lime',
    top: 110,
    left: 110,
    borderColor: 'red',
    cornerColor: 'cyan',
    cornerSize: 9,
    transparentCorners: false
  });
  
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  canvas.add(obj);
</script>
```